# Proxying objects in a deep object graph (Java)

Tags: java, reflection, proxy

```
public class ObjectToProxy
{
    List<ObjectToProxy> potentiallyCircularReference;
}

public class SubClass
{
    private ObjectToProxy aField;
    Set<ObjectToProxy> aSetOfObjectsToProxy;
}

public class CrazyObject
{
    Map<Integer, ObjectToProxy> proxiedObjects;
    List<SubClass> manySubClasses;
}

public class ComplexObject
{
    List<CrazyObject> crazyObjects;
    private final ObjectToProxy storedAsAField;
}
```

I have a complex object graph.  Lets say it looks a little like the one above (even though it is much deeper in the real system).  I would like, after being given `ComplexObject`, to be able to traverse the object graph and replace all `ObjectToProxys` with a proxying object.

Is this doable?

The reason for this is that we have some pretty big nasty objects which we partially load on the servers side (legacy, you're my friend!).  We have a semi-working solution that uses proxying on the client side to go through and loads the full object when needed.

*edit* I would like to replace every instance of `ObjectProxy` connected to a `ComplexObject`.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here.  Do you mean you want to replace each entry `v` in the map with `new Proxy(v)`?

Comment: Yes, but I'm also saying that the object graph doesn't look exactly like this. The object to be proxied could be in a map of the sub object, a field of one of the sub objects, or just about anywhere.  The above was just an example to try and show that there was some level of indirection.

Comment: Ok.  But without seeing a specific example, it's difficult to give a specific answer...

Comment: Ok, consider the above edited example a more real example of what the above graph would look like.  Given a new `ComplexObject` I would like to replace every `ObjectToProxy` connected to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static class ProxyObject extends ObjectToProxy
{
    private final ObjectToProxy objectToProxy;

    public ProxyObject(ObjectToProxy objectToProxy)
    {
        this.objectToProxy = objectToProxy;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ProxyObject";
    }
}

public static class ObjectToProxy
{
    List<ObjectToProxy> potentiallyCircularReference;

    public ObjectToProxy()
    {
        potentiallyCircularReference = new ArrayList<>();
        potentiallyCircularReference.add(this);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ObjectToProxy";
    }
}

public static class SubClass
{
    ObjectToProxy aField;
    Set<ObjectToProxy> aSetOfObjectsToProxy;
}

public static class CrazyObject
{
    Map<Integer, ObjectToProxy> proxiedObjects;
    List<SubClass> manySubClasses;

    public CrazyObject()
    {
        proxiedObjects = new HashMap<>();
        proxiedObjects.put(1, new ObjectToProxy());
    }
}

public static class ComplexObject
{
    List<CrazyObject> crazyObjects;
    final ObjectToProxy storedAsAField;

    public ComplexObject()
    {
        this.storedAsAField = new ObjectToProxy();
        crazyObjects = new ArrayList<>();
        crazyObjects.add(new CrazyObject());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "myField: " + storedAsAField.toString();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{   
    ComplexObject obj = new ComplexObject();
    Set<Object> visitedObjects = Sets.newIdentityHashSet();
    Queue<Object> objectsToVisit = new LinkedList<>();
    visitedObjects.add(obj);
    objectsToVisit.add(obj);
    while (!objectsToVisit.isEmpty())
    {
        handleFields(objectsToVisit.poll(), visitedObjects, objectsToVisit);
    }
    System.out.println(obj.toString());
}

private static void handleFields(Object obj, Set<Object> visitedObjects, Queue<Object> objectsToVisit) throws Exception
{
    List<Field> fields = getAllFields(obj);
    for (Field field : fields)
    {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object fieldValue = field.get(obj);
        if (fieldValue != null && !visitedObjects.contains(fieldValue))
        {
            if (fieldValue instanceof Object[])
            {
                visitedObjects.add(fieldValue);
                Object[] array = (Object[])fieldValue;
                for (Object arrayObj : array)
                {
                    if (arrayObj != null && !objectsToVisit.contains(arrayObj))
                    {
                        visitedObjects.add(arrayObj);
                        if (!DontLookAt.contains(arrayObj.getClass()))
                            objectsToVisit.add(arrayObj);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (!DontLookAt.contains(fieldValue.getClass()))
                    objectsToVisit.add(fieldValue);
            }
            if (fieldValue.getClass().equals(ObjectToProxy.class))
            {
                field.set(obj, new ProxyObject((ObjectToProxy)fieldValue));
            }
            else if (fieldValue instanceof ObjectToProxy[])
            {
                ObjectToProxy[] array = (ObjectToProxy[])fieldValue;
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
                {
                    if (array[i] != null)
                        array[i] = new ProxyObject(array[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private static final Set<Class> DontLookAt = getDontLookAtSet();

private static Set<Class> getDontLookAtSet()
{
    Set<Class> set = new HashSet<>();
    set.add(Long.class);
    set.add(Boolean.class);
    set.add(Integer.class);
    set.add(String.class);
    set.add(Byte.class);
    set.add(Double.class);
    set.add(Float.class);
    set.add(Class.class);
    return set;
}

private static List<Field> getAllFields(Object obj) throws Exception
{
    List<Field> output = new ArrayList<>();
    Class klazz = obj.getClass();
    while (!klazz.equals(Object.class))
    {
        Field[] fields = klazz.getDeclaredFields();
        output.addAll(Arrays.asList(fields));
        klazz = klazz.getSuperclass();
    }
    return output;
}
```

For anyone wondering, The above simulates and does what I'm after.  I'm sure it isn't perfect, but it is good enough for my purposes.